# Has anyone successfully used codedeploy on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to to use AWS codedeploy on ubuntu. The Agent does not start. 
Here's what the `Userdata` looks like:

```
"UserData" : {
                    "Fn::Base64" : {
...
                                "# Install the AWS CodeDeploy Agent.\n",
                                "aws s3 cp 's3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm' . \n",
                                "apt-get install alien",
                                "alien /root/codedeploy-agent.noarch.rpm",
                                "dpkg -i codedeploy-agent_1.0-2.727_all.deb 
> codedeploy-agent.log"****
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use alien. There is an official deb package as well. `s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/codedeploy-agent_all.deb`

You should use the install script at s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/latest/install to automatically download the latest release of the agent. Here's the user data example for Ubuntu in us-east-1 [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-set-up-new-instance.html):

`#!/bin/bash
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install awscli
apt-get -y install ruby2.0
cd /home/ubuntu
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/latest/install . --region region-name
chmod +x ./install
./install auto`

Comment: have you used it on ubuntu 14.04 or 1. i am having trouble installing it on ubuntu 14.04